# MvcSiteMapProvider - not generating sitemap.xml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, sitemap, mvcsitemapprovider

Edit: It seems like there is trouble with my Routeconfig.cs. When I removed everything except the most basic routing I can find my sitemap.xml. I'll investigate and come back with an  answer.

-

I have installed MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4 through Nuget in my MVC4 project.

My Mvc.sitemap looks like this (it's as I got it through Nuget)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mvcSiteMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0 MvcSiteMapSchema.xsd">

  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="About" controller="Home" action="About"/>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>

</mvcSiteMap>
```

I have corresponding controllers and actions in my project (although my Homecontroller has more actions which I havn't writted out in the schema)

At the bottom of my RouteConfig.cs I added this like

```
MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Mvc.XmlSiteMapController.RegisterRoutes(routes);
```

Everything compiles fine and I have made no other alterations to the code.

But when I go to localhost:xxxx/sitemap.xml I find no file (The resource cannot be found.). I was under the impression that this would work out of the box. Am I missing something?

Other things MvcSiteMapProvider does like @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMap() works just fine, but it simply does not generate the sitemap.xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a format error in my RouteConfig.cs file and the MVC route-parser simply stopped before it reached the critical code:

`MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Mvc.XmlSiteMapController.RegisterRoutes(routes);`

Make sure your RouteConfig.cs isn't stopping halfway and it should be fine.

So it was all my fault.

Comment: Actually, when using v4.0.14 or higher (and internal DI container), you do not need to include this line in your configuration, as it is now done automatically.

Comment: Okay, that's great. I havn't tested, but I suspect it would work then since I fixed my RouteConfig.